# Why do I have to put .exe to after filename to execute from the command line?

Tags: linux, gcc, command-line, command-line-interface, executable

I just installed WSL from the windows store and when I run a command such as `gcc` I have to write `gcc.exe` in order to run it. When using `which` or `echo` I don't have to put .exe.

For example

```
which gcc
(no output)

which gcc.exe
/mnt/c/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe

which java
(no output)

which java.exe
/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath/java.exe

java -version
Command 'java' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless  # version 11.0.8+10-0ubuntu1~20.04, or
sudo apt install default-jre              # version 2:1.11-72
sudo apt install openjdk-13-jre-headless  # version 13.0.3+3-1ubuntu2
sudo apt install openjdk-14-jre-headless  # version 14.0.1+7-1ubuntu1
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless   # version 8u252-b09-1ubuntu1

java.exe -version
java version "1.8.0_281"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_281-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.281-b09, mixed mode)
```

Does anyone know why I have to put .exe after certain programs but not functions like `which` or `echo`

Comment: `which` and `echo` are shell builtins, or standalone Linux executables.  You are "selecting" the Windows version of `gcc` and `java`.when you add the `.exe` suffix.  Check your `PATH` variable. If it is OK, looks like you may not have Linux versions of `gcc` and `java` installed.

Comment: `which` is not a bash builtin. Use `command -v` or `type` instead.

Comment: @glennjackman. The OP has not informed us if they are using `bash` or not.  They may be using a shell where `which` is a shell builtin - such as `zsh`.

Comment: I'm using the Ubuntu windows store app.